# How to add a name to a grouped column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

Can someone please help with the following question: When I use a group by, the result I get a time_counts frame, but the new grouped column has no name. How do I give it a name?

```
import pandas as pd

def read_data():
    df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", usecols=['time', 'unix_time', 'name'])
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
    df['unix_time'] = (df['unix_time']).astype(int)


    time_counts = df.groupby(df['time'].dt.floor('S'))['time'].count()
    print(time_counts)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_data()
```

output is:

```
time
2022-12-15 08:00:18    1
2022-12-15 08:07:17    1
2022-12-15 08:12:09    1
2022-12-15 08:12:19    1
2022-12-15 08:13:04    1
```

desired output is :

```
time                   count
2022-12-15 08:00:18    1
2022-12-15 08:07:17    1
2022-12-15 08:12:09    1
2022-12-15 08:12:19    1
2022-12-15 08:13:04    1
```

data in csv is :

```
time                    unix_time       name
2022-12-15 08:00:18.034 1671091218034   apple
2022-12-15 08:07:17.376 1671091637376   apple
2022-12-15 08:12:09.648 1671091929648   apple
2022-12-15 08:12:19.320 1671091939320   apple
2022-12-15 08:13:04.623 1671091984623   apple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this,I did no changes except this line:

```
time_counts = df.groupby(df['time'].dt.floor('S'))['time'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

```
                 time  count
0 2022-12-15 08:00:18      1
1 2022-12-15 08:07:17      1
2 2022-12-15 08:12:09      1
3 2022-12-15 08:12:19      1
4 2022-12-15 08:13:04      1
```

Note that the output you created was a `pd.Series`, with my added content `time_counts` is a `pd.DataFrame`.

Answer (score 2):

Using .[agg()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) you can set column name and aggregate:

```
time_counts = df.groupby(df["time"].dt.floor("S")).agg(count=("time", "count")).reset_index()
print(time_counts)
```

Output:

```
                 time  count
0 2022-12-15 08:00:18      1
1 2022-12-15 08:07:17      1
2 2022-12-15 08:12:09      1
3 2022-12-15 08:12:19      1
4 2022-12-15 08:13:04      1
```